# Python "int object not iterable" after list() a map object

Tags: python

The following simple code returns an error, even with `list()`:

```
map(max,[1,2,3,4])
Out[123]: <map at 0xdff50f0320>
list(map(max,[1,2,3,4]))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I used `list` to map object is to display the content; it seems not work this way.  How to see the map object?

Comment: `map(max, [1,2,3,4])` calls `max(1)`, then `max(2)`, then `max(3)`, then `max(4)`. None of those calls make any sense. What did you _want_ it to call? Just `max([1,2,3,4])` without `map`? Or something different?

Comment: The reason you don't get an error from just `map(max, [1,2,3,4])` without the `list(…)` is that you're just creating the map iterator. It doesn't try to call `map(1)` (which raises the exception) until you try to use the iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` applies the given function to *each* element of the iterable object that follows.  What you've tried to do is to take the maximum of four integers, *individually*.  Since `max` *also* requires an iterable object, this fails.

Usage example:

```
l = [
      [1, 2, 3, 4],
      [3.14, 2.7, 6.023, -5],
      ['Python', 'Java', 'R']
    ]

large = map(max, l)
for big in large:
    print (big)
```

Output:

```
4
6.023
R
```

Comment: great. Thanks for pointing out max() is done individually. Also appreciate the point from the other comment why there's no error in map(). By the way, the example didn't mean to have any meaningful usage. Just highlight the error.